# Granting permanent file access permissions to application in Windows 10 from the command line

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe, uac

I am currently working on an application which needs full access to the users home directory and mass storage devices.

I am searching an simple solution to grant permanent access to these directories to an application or to grant an application permanent administration rights without prompting an Windows UAC dialog every time the application is executed. My goal is to run this command during the installation with an exec command. My installation routine is run with full administrator rights. The only solution here on Stack Overflow which I can find is 11 years old and only mentions how to grant access to a folder to a user ([How to grant permission to users for a directory using command line in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928738/how-to-grant-permission-to-users-for-a-directory-using-command-line-in-windows)). In Windows 10 applications seem to be blocked to access some folders even when the user has access to them (e.g. Downloads folder).

Comment: You would have to disable your users' security. Please rethink what you are trying to do. Thousand of apps to not have to tinker with security. Windows 11 will probably stop you completely.

Comment: Can't I just disable the security for one specific application? I basically just want my application to have the same rights as the Explorer. I do not need anything from an System folder and I do not even have to write there.

Comment: Also just wondering, what do Antivirus Software do, to monitor all folders, without having to prompt UAC every time?

Comment: You need to set up a standard approach to installing software that Users run (not you) so they can manage security safely.  NO, you cannot disable someone else's security for one app. You need to understand how good software is installed safely by users.

Comment: "I can" or "I should"? To be clear, the program would have administrator rights during installation. I do not understand what you mean with someone else's security. This have to be installed by the user himself.

Comment: You need a user to install your package so they can administer Security. Allowing "someone" else to safely manage security should only be Microsoft and perhaps Lenovo.

Comment: Again. I don't want access to System folders. I just want access to stuff to which the user has access. So I really don't see why this shouldn't be possible security wise.

Comment: The only way to avoid the UAC dialog is to completely disable it.

Answer (score 1):

As the installation of your product requires already administrative
permissions, your question does have a solution, although it requires
the heavy restructuring of your application.

You would need to divide the application into two:

- System service that has full access to the computer,
- The main program that calls the system service to access the needed
  files.

As the system service can become a major security problem, the interface
of your program to it must be extremely secure.

Comment: You can easily infer from the OP's questions that the App will not be secure in any way. It will completely fail in Windows 11.

Comment: @John At the moment this is more of an University exercise. I really doubt this project will be around when Windows 10 is out of support. And even if it is, I may be able to implement another solution.

Comment: How can I create a System service?

Comment: A University should not be suggesting you unsecure someone else's computer.

Comment: Could we focus on the technical aspects? Stuff like this is great for the evaluation for the written document. At the moment I am searching an technical solution for an technical problem. The Pros and Cons is something to consider in another step.

Comment: A system service is usually a C program. If you have no experience with Windows API and C, the route is long.

Comment: So when this is so complicated. Can't I just show the user manually how to lift these protections? Do you know if this can easily be changed by the user?

Comment: A standard user cannot run as admin. See if you can use a program such as [RunAsSpc](https://www.robotronic.de/runasspcen.html), although this will require knowing the name & password of an admin account on the target computer.

Comment: @Alfondo6 - Telling you the method you describe is insecure is sticking to the technical parts of your question.  UAC can only be disabled with a group policy. There is no way to bypass UAC, AV are only able to scan, the files the user (which installed it) has access to.  UAC CANNOT be "temporarily lifted", it's either enable or disabled, if it's disabled that opens an entirely different bag of worms.

Comment: Again. accessing the files the user has access to, is all I want. The problem is that Windows 10 is restricting access to user owned resources. Examples are the Download or the Document folder. These are the folders that I need. By the way. What my application is doing is monitoring the system in real time and calculating hashes and CRC values of files. The idea is to detect data corruptions. I know there are other applciations which do the same, but you know how this is with university projects.

Comment: For me, `C:\Users\user-name` has full-control permissions for account `user-name`, so I must admit that I do not really understand the problem.

Comment: Try to access C:\Users\user-name\Downloads from an standard windows installation via an application.

Comment: Did it - no problem. I found some left-overs in the folder and used the opportunity to delete them.